# How to fix "Function returned undefined, expected Promise or value"

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, promise, google-cloud-functions

What I am trying to accomplish in a Firebase Function:

1. Read from Firebase database email addresses to batch email.
2. Loop through each one and send out emails.

I am having an issue with closing promises I believe. These don't need to be ran in order, I just need to resolve all promises before ending.

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();
const https = require('axios');

exports.sendEmail = functions.pubsub.topic('nightly_topic').onPublish(() => {

    let emailsToSend = [];

    async function getTests (){
         admin.firestore()
         .collection("tests")
         .get()
         .then(querySnapshot => {
            querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
                emailsToSend.push(doc.data())
            });
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            console.error(error);
        });
    }

    async function send (address){
        let body = { 
             //MANDRILL INFO REMOVED
        };

        let endpoint = 'https://mandrillapp.com/api/1.0/messages/send-template.json';

        https.post(endpoint, body)
            .then((result) => {
                console.log('SUCCESS');
            })
            .catch(function (error) {
                console.error(error);
            });
    }

    async function init() {
        await getTests();

        for (const email of emailsToSend) {
            await send(email.address);
        }
    }

    init();

});
```

Comment: Your function needs to return a promise that resolves when all the async work in your function is complete.  Right now, your function isn't returning anything.

Comment: Yes @DougStevenson, that is what the problem description states in my question.

Comment: It sounds like you understand how to proceed.  Is there something specific you're stuck on?

Comment: @DougStevenson please read the question again if you are here to help - I am having trouble figuring out where I am missing a Promise return and resolve. If you are just here to troll please find another post.

Comment: I am just trying to make sure you understand what the error message is saying.  You should look into the use of `Promise.all()` to create a new promise that resolves or rejects with all the other promises you are working with

Answer (score 0):

You're missing return statements from your functions.
`return https.post(...` etc

Comment: Yes @andy-lamb, that is what the problem description states in my question

Comment: @ChefBrian So... you know the error is caused by you missing return statements. So when you tried to add those return statements in, what happened? Why did that not fix the issue? Did another error occur? What was it?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();
const https = require('axios');

exports.sendEmail = functions.pubsub.topic('nightly_topic').onPublish(() => {

    let emailsToSend = [];

    function getTests (){
         return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            admin.firestore()
            .collection("tests")
            .get()
            .then(querySnapshot => {
              querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
                emailsToSend.push(doc.data())
              });
            resolve(emailsToSend);
          })
        .catch(function (error) {
            reject(error)
        });
       });
    }

    async function send (address){
        let body = { 
             //MANDRILL INFO REMOVED
        };

        let endpoint = 'https://mandrillapp.com/api/1.0/messages/send-template.json';

        https.post(endpoint, body)
            .then((result) => {
                console.log('SUCCESS');
            })
            .catch(function (error) {
                console.error(error);
            });
    }

    async function init() {
        const emailsToSend = await getTests();

        for (const email of emailsToSend) {
            await send(email.address);
        }
    }

    init();

});
```

It might help you.

Comment: This won't help. The function needs to return a promise that resolves when all the async work is complete.  Right now, it's returning nothing.

Comment: Console emailsToSend value from getTests funtion and see either value exist or not

Answer (score 0):

so you are almost there. The issue is that you are not returning anything. You should fix it by just doing:

#### Return Promise

```
// code ...

exports.sendEmail = functions.pubsub.topic('nightly_topic').onPublish(() => {
    // code

    return init();
}
```

#### Use async

```
// code ...

exports.sendEmail = functions.pubsub.topic('nightly_topic').onPublish(async () => {
    // code

    await init();
}
```

**Note:** an async function always returns a Promise.

### Suggestion

In your code, you are sending emails one at a time. `await send(email.address);` This line of code waits until the email is sent, before sending the next one, which is not efficient.

My suggestion is sending all emails at the same time and return a promise that resolves when every email is sent. That should look something like this:

```
//change this 
for (const email of emailsToSend) {
  await send(email.address);
}

// --------------into this--------------------------------

//This is an array of promises
const promises = emailsToSend.map(email => {
    return send(email.address);
});

await Promise.all(promises);
```

Hope that helps :)